# Prove using Natural Deduction method if valid, or prove invalid using Shortcut Method for which I provided a proof deduction, does this suffice?

Tags: logic

M ⊃ N

O ⊃ P

├ (M ∧ O) ⊃ (N ∧ P)

1:    M⊃N                       premise

2:    O⊃P                       premise

3:      M∧O                  assumption

4:         M                    ∧E 3

5:         N                    ⊃E 1 4

6:         O                    ∧E 3

7:         P                    ⊃E 2 6

8:         N∧P                  ∧I 5 7

9:    M∧O⊃N∧P                   ⊃I 3 8

∴ Statement is Valid

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: I apologize! I will post it up as separate questions. Thank you!

Comment: Just edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is valid.  Here's a mathjax presentation.

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\qquad\fitch{~~1.~~M\supset N\hspace{13ex}\text{premise}
\\~~2.~~O\supset P\hspace{14ex}\text{premise}}
{\fitch{~~3.~~M\wedge O\hspace{10ex}\text{assumption}}{
~~4.~~M\hspace{15ex}\wedge\mathrm E~3
\\~~5.~~N\hspace{15ex}\supset\mathrm E~1,~4
\\~~6.~~O\hspace{15ex}\wedge\mathrm E~3
\\~~7.~~P\hspace{15ex}\supset\mathrm E~2,~6
\\~~8.~~N\wedge P\hspace{10.5ex}\wedge\mathrm I~5,~7}
\\~~9.~~M\wedge O~\supset~N\wedge P\hspace{2.5ex}\supset\mathrm I~3,~8}$